# how to slice data frame by row number and aggregate in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

how could i use group_by function by sequential rows, for example, 
how could I calculate the sum for each seven rows, such as the sum of 1-7 rows and the sum of 8-14 row?

```
  values

1   4
2   2
3   1
4   5
6   1
7   8
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use integer division by helper array created by `np.arange` be length of `DataFrame` and pass to `groupby` for aggregate `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 7).sum()
print (df)
   values
0      21
```